# Xcode IAP stuck at waiting for upload

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am attempting to put an in app purchase in my app. It is non consumable. I have added all the necessary code to the binary. I have also added localizations. Here are screenshots: when content hosting is enabled: [image: With content hosting]

When it is not: [image]

It's a very strange error and it says at the top with the blue exclamation mark as follows: "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below." Rejecting my own binary did not do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: I am struck at the same scenario. I have added all the necessary data but it still shows the status as waiting for upload. I am not able to proceed further because of this. Until the status is ready for submit, We can't select the IAP in the Appstore section. Please let me know on how to get the IAP to *Ready to Submit*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you also added all the necessary Review Information for this in-app purchase? You need to provide a screenshot of the in-app purchase and optional review notes. This might be the reason iTunes Connect is missing metadata.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Please try **Turning Off Content Hosting** and you should be able to see the status changed to **Ready to Submit**. Though it is optional to upload the Promotional Screenshot, Make sure you add all the fields including the Review Screenshot and Review Description